# Trying to alter JSON so it displays over multiple rows instead of single line using JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, not working

Tags: json, parsing, format

Here are my results:

```
[{"android_id":"4b76f380a2734530","date":"11\/11\/1992","entry":"Ate a peanut"},{"android_id":"4b76f380a2734530","date":"11\/11\/1994","entry":"Ate an banana"}]
```

What I want it to look like:

```
[
 {
  "android_id": "4b76f380a2734530",
  "date": "11\/11\/1992",
  "entry": "Ate a peanut"
 },
 {
  "android_id": "4b76f380a2734530",
  "date": "11\/11\/1994",
  "entry": "Ate an banana"
 }
]
```

I'm trying to use the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT function but it doesn't like it even thought I'm using PHP 5.6:

My code:

```
// Pring data as json string.
$json = json_encode($diary_entrys);
$json_string = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I should have used decode instead of encode, works fine now.